# passing dictionary as parameter in csp python gives unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, constraint-satisfaction

I am applying the CSP in python having problem when passing dictionary as a parameter to a method in python

```
officerDomain = range(0, 2**scheduleDays-1)

solver = MinConflictsSolver()
problem = Problem(solver)

officers = []
officers.append({'name':'Ryan', 'rank':'3'})
officers.append({'name':'Mond', 'rank':'1'})
officers.append({'name':'Eric', 'rank':'3'})


for officer in officers:
    print(officer)
    problem.addVariable(officer, officerDomain)
```

While passing the dictionary inside the list it gives the error **unhashable type: 'dict'**

Answer (score 0):

Let's read the [documentation](http://labix.org/doc/constraint/public/constraint.Problem-class.html#addVariable):

> `addVariable(self, variable, domain)`
>
> **Parameters**:
>   *variable* - Object representing a problem variable (type=hashable object)

So you can't use a dictionary (officer in this case) because it's unhashable. Try with `officer["name"]` for example.